# move from unique_ptr to stack variable

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, move-semantics

Is it possible to create a stack variable (of type `T` with a move constructor) from a `std::unique_ptr<T>`?

I tried something like

```
std::unique_ptr<T> p = ext_get_my_pointer();   // external call returns a smart pointer
T val{std::move(*p.release())};                // I actually need a stack variable
```

but it looks ugly, and creates a memory leak apparently. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a memory leak because you have decoupled the allocated memory from the unique_ptr, but it is still allocated.
Assuming you have a functioning move constructor, why not:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> p = ext_get_my_pointer(); 
T val{std::move(*p)};
// p goes out of scope so is freed at the end of the block, or you can call `p.reset()` explicitly.
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it creates a memory leak, because with `p.release()` you say that you take responsibility for the object, and due to that you need to `delete` it.

You would do something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> p = ext_get_my_pointer();   // external call returns a smart pointer
T val{std::move(*p)};
p.reset(nullptr);
```

Comment: `*p` is enough, no need of `*p.get()`.

Comment: the memory leak is not for the resource, but for the T itself. gotcha thanks